# Parsing IMDB-API JSON

Tags: java, json

I am trying to parse JSON movie info provided by http://www.omdbapi.com (Example: http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=Lord%20Of%20the%20rings) using the JSON Simple lib but am having no success. I keep getting the error org.json.simple.JSONObject cannot be cast to org.json.simple.JSONArray.

Having a look at the site and at the repose I cannot figure out why it cannot parse the info. I am using the standard example provided below with no success. Any help or an alternative JSON lib that will work will be appreciated.

s being the String I get from the website:

```
JSONParser parser=new JSONParser();
Object obj = parser.parse(s);
JSONArray array = (JSONArray)obj;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON you retrieve from the API is

```
{"Search":[{"Title":"The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring","Year":"2001","imdbID":"tt0120737","Type":"movie"},{"Title":"The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King","Year":"2003","imdbID":"tt0167260","Type":"movie"},{"Title":"The Lord of the Rings: The Two Towers","Year":"2002","imdbID":"tt0167261","Type":"movie"},{"Title":"The Lord of the Rings","Year":"1978","imdbID":"tt0077869","Type":"movie"},{"Title":"The Lord of the Rings: The Two Towers","Year":"2002","imdbID":"tt0347436","Type":"game"},{"Title":"The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King","Year":"2003","imdbID":"tt0387360","Type":"game"},{"Title":"The Lord of the Rings: The Battle for Middle-Earth","Year":"2004","imdbID":"tt0412935","Type":"game"},{"Title":"Lord of the Rings: Battle for Middle Earth II - Rise of the Witch King","Year":"2006","imdbID":"tt1058040","Type":"game"},{"Title":"The Lord of the Rings: The Battle for Middle-Earth II","Year":"2006","imdbID":"tt0760172","Type":"game"},{"Title":"The Lord of the Rings: The Third Age","Year":"2004","imdbID":"tt0415947","Type":"game"}]}
```

It starts with `{`. That is a JSON object (`JSONObject`), not an array (`JSONArray`).

```
Object obj = parser.parse(s);
```

`Object obj`'s dynamic type will be `JSONObject` which cannot be cast to `JSONArray`.

If you want the internal array, use one of the `get()` methods of `JSONObject`, with key `"Search"`.